# Quartz scheduler trigger fires only 10 times

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I wrote a Quartz scheduler for firing every 2 minutes. 
It runs and fire only 10 times. 
After 10th time the trigger doesn't  fire.

Trigger

```
 trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                            .WithIdentity(triggerName)
                            .WithSimpleSchedule(builder => builder.WithIntervalInSeconds(1).RepeatForever())
                            .StartNow()
                            .Build();
```

Job

```
JobDetailImpl  jobDetail = new JobDetailImpl(jobName , group ,jobExecution.GetType() ,true ,true);
```

and

```
 _quartzScheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail , trigger1 );

                _quartzScheduler.Start();
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: i updated with code of my job scheduler

Comment: I guess your problem is with `WithRepeatCount(20)`. Remove it, I guess it should work.

Comment: I remove and check but it fires only 10 times

Comment: I found why this stop at 10th time. that because  Quartz default threadCount is 10. then it will stop at that time. we can increase the threadCount in web config  section.
But I don't know how to release threads  used before the application. otherwise i have to limit in the thread count that means trigger times.